# Keyframes animation not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, css-animations

This animation is working perfectly in Safari and Chrome, but isn't working in Firefox.

I've tried a few things including `-moz` prefixes

Can anyone offer me advice on what's wrong here?

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxZps/1/)

### HTML

```
<span class="awesome">
    <span class="underline"></span>
    <span class="underline2"></span>
    awesome
</span>
```

### CSS

```
span.awesome{
    position: relative;
}
span.underline{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
    animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
}
span.underline2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 110px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes underline{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    20%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    28%{
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    36%{
        width: 0px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes underline{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    20%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    28%{
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    36%{
        width: 0px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a typo – the last value read `0%` instead of `100%`

Don't need to specify `-moz` selectors for CSS3 animations in the latest versions of Firefox, but thanks for your suggestion, @Unykvis

### Corrected CSS:

```
span.awesome{
    position: relative;
}
span.underline{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
    animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
}
span.underline2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 110px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes underline{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    20%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    28%{
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    36%{
        width: 0px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes underline{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    20%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    28%{
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    36%{
        width: 0px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0px;
    }
}
```

---

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxZps/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the -moz- to the keyframe animation and also to the selector.
Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/DxZps/4/

CSS:

```
span.underline{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
    animation: underline 2s linear infinite;
}


@-moz-keyframes underline{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    20%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    28%{
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    36%{
        width: 0px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    0%{
        width: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – it wasn't the `-moz` selector, but instead it was a typo.